# Haskell's type signature of u f=f.f is stronger than I would like

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-signature

I wrote the following simple function

```
u f=f.f
```

According to `ghci` this has the type signature of

```
u :: (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

However that type signature is too strict.  Haskell is enforcing that our input be of type `(b -> b)` when it shouldn't necessarily need to be.  For example the function `(:[])` has the type signature of

```
(:[]) :: a -> [a]
```

Which is not of the form `(b -> b)`, (unless you allow infinite types) and thus can't be passed to `u`.  However you can compose `(:[])` with itself.

```
g=(:[]).(:[])
```

This works and has the type

```
(:[]).(:[]) :: a -> [[a]]
```

So I should be, in principle, able to pass this to `u`.

I tried to write a new type signature myself to replace the generated signature but I could not come up with a way to express the requirements of the function.  I always come up with the same type signature that the compiler provides.  Is there a type signature we can give to weaken the `u` so that functions like `(:[])` can be passed to it?

Comment: Your example is not equivalent to `u f = f . f`. In `g=(:[]).(:[])`, each `(:[])` has a different type. In `u f = f . f`, each `f` must have the same type.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Yes that is the problem.

Comment: And it is also why the problem has no solution. There is only one `f` and it may only have one type.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs So there is simply no way to make a function that allows us to self compose any self-composable function?

Comment: No, `u` us that function. What you are trying to pass to it is not a self-composable function. The only self-composable functions are functions of type `a -> a`.

Comment: Look at it another way: `u f` is the theorem that `f` is a self-composable function. The fact that `u (:[])` does not type-check is evidence that `(:[])` is not a self-composable function.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I think we are operating under different definitions of self-composable.  When I say self-composable I mean a function that can be composed with itself. `(:[])` by that definition is self composable since it can be composed with itself.

Comment: The two `(:[])` in `(:[]) . (:[])` *are not the same function*. They inhabid different types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162231/discussion-between-epsilon-neighborhood-watch-and-rein-henrichs).

Comment: This is an excellent question. Think `RankNTypes`. When are *polymorphic* functions composable?

Comment: `let u :: (forall a. a -> f a) -> b -> f (f b); u f = f . f`

Comment: but now `u not` doesn't typecheck

Comment: If you’re curious, a type system feature that would enable this is *intersection types*, which Haskell doesn’t support. In such a system, `u` would have the type `(a -> b /\ b -> c) -> a -> c`. You can think of an intersection of function types as the type of an overloaded function, or as the least upper bound of the types; in Haskell’s type system, the least upper bound *that you can express* for `a -> b` and `b -> c` is exactly what you got: `a -> a` (where `a ~ b ~ c`). This also hints that `forall` represents an infinite intersection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are lots of different functions that can do this for specific cases, but none that work in general.

```
u1 :: (forall a. a -> f a) -> b -> f (f b)
u2 :: (forall a. f a -> a) -> f (f b) -> b
```

and infinitely more are possible. But the function

```
u f x = f (f x)
```

does not *have* a most general type in Haskell when `RankNTypes` is in play. As pigworker notes, there are type systems that can give `u` a principle type of the sort you desire, but they take type system extension in a very different direction from the ones that Haskell designers have focused on.

Comment: Fans of intersection types (I'm not, but I know a few) might beg to differ.

Comment: @pigworker, what might it look like if we had those?

Comment: Writing `&` for intersection, `((a -> b) & (b -> c)) -> (a -> c)`.

Comment: @pigworker, ah, I see. Seems rather unlikely to show up in Haskell.

Comment: Ah, but then the explanation would be "Haskell disallows meaningful things", and a note of contrition would be appropriate.

Comment: @pigworker - *all* non-trivial consistent type systems disallow meaningful things.   That's a direct consequence of Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: @pigworker I've always found bravado to be the best course for the Haskeller in these and similar situations.

Comment: @Jules That just means some contrition is inevitable. "We can't do everything so we shouldn't do better." is the argument you are making. I'd rather think about how to do better.